# Sql like statement - Returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the title is not good i don't know how to explain that.

I have table like

```
Id    AvaibleSports
1     [1]
2     [1]
3     [2],[10]
4     [4],[10]
```

I know this is not the best way to store information but this is all i have right now. I need to filter rows based on avaible sports value.

For example when i filter for "1" i must get records 1 and 2. When i filter for "10", i need to get 3 and 4 back.

I tried to filter with like statement like this:

```
select Id, AvaibleSports FROM myTable wHERE AvaibleSports like '%[10]%'
```

but this is also returning records containing [1].

I also tried to filter like

```
select Id, AvaibleSports FROM myTable wHERE AvaibleSports like '%10%'
```

This is returning correct result for 10 but wrong result for 1.

How can i filter this correctly?

Comment: Why do you store multiple values in one column? Instead store the right type in another table which is linked with this via foreign-key.

Comment: I.e. one row for each available sport!

Comment: Like the dup says: `AvaibleSports like '%\[10\]%' escape '\'`

Comment: @wewesthemenace: Possibly, but I think `escape` is an ANSI standard.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, just offering another solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can alternately use `CHARINDEX` . Something like this.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
AvaibleSports VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @table1(AvaibleSports)
SELECT '[1]' a
UNION ALL SELECT '[1]'
UNION ALL SELECT '[2],[10]'
UNION ALL SELECT '[4],[10]'

SELECT * FROM @table1 WHERE CHARINDEX('[10]',AvaibleSports) > 0
```